# Form Helper X Form Builder. What's the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm Brazilian... Sorry for my English errors of type.

I need to make a form helper, but I'm confused.
I would like to know the difference between a Form Helper and a Form Builder.

Hallo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather 'builders are a kind of helper'

That's not a very useful answer, and I'd be grateful if anyone else can provide a better one.